# What are all the reference files produced by bwa index, and are these dependent upon whether the reference is zipped?

Tags: bwa, samtools, reference-genome

I have indexed a gzipped reference with bwa: `bwa index reference.fa.gz`, which produces a series of other files `reference.fa.gz.{amb,ann,bwt,pac,sa}`. These are working fine with bwa alignment.

I have discovered that samtools does not take a gzipped reference, so I am planning to use an unzipped version of the reference for my workflow instead of dealing with two separate representations of the reference.

Are the files `reference.fa.gz.{amb,ann,bwt,pac,sa}` dependent upon the reference being gzipped? Do I need to reindex the unzipped reference.fa with bwa, or can I just rename the current files to remove the `.gz` portion of the filename?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll get the exact same index (the `amb`, `ann`, `bwt`, `pac` and `sa` files) whether the reference is gzipped or not. BWA also makes its own packed reference sequence (the .pac file) so you don't even need the genome around after you index.